# Getting Warning: - OptionalDouble.getAsDouble() without isPresent() check

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

How would I apply this `isPresent()` check along with this condition?

```
static Predicate<Student> averageMarksGreaterThan40 = student -> student.getMarks().stream()
            .mapToInt(i -> i).average().getAsDouble() > 40;
```

I tried applying `orElse(null)` also before calling `getAsDouble()` but it is also not solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should rephrase your question based on what your predicate is doing: your predicate is about finding all students whose average marks is greater than 40.

Which should bring the question: *what is the average of a student having no marks?*

In most case, it would be 0 - which amount to use `orElse(0)`:

```
static Predicate<Student> averageMarksGreaterThan40 = student -> student.getMarks()
   .stream()
   .mapToInt(i -> i)
   .average()
   .orElse(0) > 40; // so, no isPresent()
```

If you were to use `isPresent()` - that's possible - but that useless here because the `orElse(double)` is already doing so.

```java
    static Predicate<Student> averageMarksGreaterThan40 = student -> {
  OptionalDouble average =  student.getMarks()
       .stream()
       .mapToInt(i -> i)
       .average();

      return average.isPresent() && average.getAsDouble() > 40;
   }
```

Using `orElseThrow(...)` here on the other hand would be *good* only if you are testing that student do have marks, otherwise this would fails:

```java
var students = new ArrayList<Student>(); // the students
var studentsWithAverageMarksGreaterThan40 = students.stream()
  .filter(student -> !student.getMarks().isEmpty())
  .filter(averageMarksGreaterThan40)
  .toList()
;
```

I don't think that's a good choice in the case of a predicate.

You could also use `OptionalDouble::stream` and `anyMatch`, but I think `orElse(0)` is far easier to read/understand:

```java
    static Predicate<Student> averageMarksGreaterThan40 = student -> student.getMarks()
       .stream()
       .mapToInt(i -> i)
       .average()
       .stream()
       .anyMatch(avg -> avg -> 40)
       ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Terminal operation `average()` returns an optional because if stream is empty, result might not be present.

Method `getAsDouble()` will throw `NoSuchElementException` when invoked on an empty optional object. But it might not obvious to the reader of your code.

If you are certain that value has to be present [`orElseThrow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#orElseThrow()) will be a better alternative, because it makes your intention to throw if incorrect behavior occurs explicit.

Another option is to use [`orElse(defaultValue)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#orElse(double)) that expects a default value, or [`orElseGet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/OptionalDouble.html#orElseGet(java.util.function.DoubleSupplier)) that takes a `DoubleSupplier`.

---

> How would I apply this `isPresent()` check

You can't check it inside a stream, method `isPresent()` needs to be invoked on an optional object.

> I tried applying `orElse(null)` also before calling `getAsDouble()`

That will not compile because method `orElse()` returns a value, not an optional. Therefore, call `getAsDouble()` is redundant.

Providing `null` as default value isn't a good idea. Optionals are designed as mean to avoid `null` values, and in your case it will immediately produce a `NullPointerException`.